# Rails segmentation fault using mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm developing a simple RESTful api with rails and after calling the index a few times (like 3-4 times) and everything breaks.
I've checked for memory leaks and memory usage seems fine, also CPU consumption is pretty low.

The main thing I don't understand is why it doesn't break on the first try, rather after repeating the exact same request a few times.

```
/home/jafuentest/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/forwardable.rb:228: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000038
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0170 p:0045 s:1070 e:001067 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/forwardable.rb:228
c:0169 p:0042 s:1061 E:000960 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/collection/view/builder/op_query.rb:49
c:0168 p:0051 s:1050 E:0009d8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:67
c:0167 p:0023 s:1044 E:000a48 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:81
c:0166 p:0027 s:1039 E:000b50 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:41
c:0165 p:0023 s:1034 E:000c00 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/retryable.rb:43
c:0164 p:0015 s:1028 E:000b10 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:39
c:0163 p:0033 s:1024 E:000cf0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/query_cache.rb:222 [FINISH]
c:0162 p:---- s:1018 E:000ab0 CFUNC  :first
c:0161 p:0063 s:1014 E:000d78 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:257
c:0160 p:0057 s:1008 E:000e28 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:522
c:0159 p:0041 s:1001 E:000118 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:255
c:0158 p:0022 s:0996 E:000f00 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:20
c:0157 p:0062 s:0988 E:000f80 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/relations/builders/referenced/in.rb:20
c:0156 p:0032 s:0982 E:001010 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:42
c:0155 p:0012 s:0974 E:0010a0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:25
c:0154 p:0063 s:0966 E:001190 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:103
c:0153 p:0026 s:0963 E:001230 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:130
c:0152 p:0009 s:0959 E:001160 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:99
c:0151 p:0026 s:0956 E:001310 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:89
c:0150 p:0046 s:0952 E:001138 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:98
c:0149 p:0019 s:0943 E:0013d0 LAMBDA /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:186 [FINISH]
c:0148 p:0011 s:0938 E:001440 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/web-app/app/views/api/stories/_story.json.jbuilder:17
c:0147 p:0007 s:0934 E:001500 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder.rb:38
c:0146 p:0007 s:0931 E:0015f0 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder.rb:266
c:0145 p:0030 s:0928 E:0016a0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder.rb:305
c:0144 p:0073 s:0922 E:0015b8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder.rb:266
c:0143 p:0059 s:0915 E:0014d0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder.rb:38
c:0142 p:0065 s:0907 E:0017b0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb:100
c:0141 p:0043 s:0899 E:001858 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder.rb:66
c:0140 p:0137 s:0894 E:0019c0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/web-app/app/views/api/stories/_story.json.jbuilder:16
c:0139 p:0029 s:0882 E:001910 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:157
c:0138 p:0047 s:0879 E:001990 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168
c:0137 p:0025 s:0873 E:001a38 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:352
c:0136 p:0012 s:0868 E:001208 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:155
c:0135 p:0117 s:0859 E:001080 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:342
c:0134 p:0008 s:0848 E:001ba8 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42
c:0133 p:0014 s:0844 E:001c80 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166
c:0132 p:0028 s:0841 E:001d40 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21
c:0131 p:0033 s:0833 E:001c50 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166
c:0130 p:0071 s:0827 E:001b70 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41
c:0129 p:0011 s:0821 E:000110 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:331
c:0128 p:0109 s:0817 E:001e88 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:310
c:0127 p:0026 s:0810 E:001f08 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47
c:0126 p:0023 s:0803 E:001f80 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21
c:0125 p:0094 s:0797 E:002008 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:32
c:0124 p:0077 s:0790 E:002088 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/haml-5.0.3/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:14
c:0123 p:0026 s:0783 E:0020f8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb:128
c:0122 p:0048 s:0778 E:002170 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb:119
c:0121 p:0008 s:0773 E:002210 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder.rb:298
c:0120 p:0030 s:0770 E:0022c0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder.rb:305
c:0119 p:0009 s:0764 E:0021e8 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder.rb:298 [FINISH]
c:0118 p:---- s:0760 e:000759 IFUNC 
c:0117 p:0053 s:0757 E:002388 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:696
c:0116 p:0013 s:0749 E:002408 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:133
c:0115 p:0008 s:0745 E:002478 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:45
c:0114 p:0008 s:0741 E:0024e8 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:111 [FINISH]
c:0113 p:---- s:0737 e:000736 CFUNC  :each
c:0112 p:0015 s:0733 E:0006c0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:111
c:0111 p:0031 s:0729 E:0002c0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongo-2.4.3/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:44
c:0110 p:0033 s:0725 E:0004a0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/query_cache.rb:222
c:0109 p:0020 s:0719 E:000258 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:132 [FINISH]
c:0108 p:---- s:0714 E:001960 CFUNC  :map
c:0107 p:0023 s:0710 E:000560 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:324
c:0106 p:0022 s:0704 E:000620 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/mongoid-6.2.1/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:20
c:0105 p:0010 s:0696 E:000638 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder.rb:297
c:0104 p:0060 s:0691 E:000718 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder.rb:188
c:0103 p:0059 s:0684 E:0007d8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb:90
c:0102 p:0099 s:0677 E:001bf0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb:115
c:0101 p:0150 s:0669 E:0008b0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb:215
c:0100 p:0045 s:0661 E:000928 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb:22
c:0099 p:0045 s:0656 E:0009a8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/jbuilder-2.7.0/lib/jbuilder/jbuilder_template.rb:88
c:0098 p:0062 s:0649 E:000a40 METHOD /home/jafuentest/web-app/app/views/api/stories/index.json.jbuilder:1
c:0097 p:0029 s:0639 E:000ab0 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:157
c:0096 p:0047 s:0636 E:000b30 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168
c:0095 p:0025 s:0630 E:000bd8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:352
c:0094 p:0012 s:0625 E:0010b8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/template.rb:155
c:0093 p:0017 s:0616 E:000f70 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52
c:0092 p:0008 s:0613 E:000d48 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42
c:0091 p:0014 s:0609 E:000e20 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166
c:0090 p:0028 s:0606 E:000ee0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21
c:0089 p:0033 s:0598 E:000df0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166
c:0088 p:0071 s:0592 E:000d10 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41
c:0087 p:0023 s:0586 E:000f48 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:51
c:0086 p:0038 s:0582 E:001068 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59
c:0085 p:0036 s:0573 E:000f10 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:50
c:0084 p:0107 s:0565 E:001138 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14
c:0083 p:0024 s:0558 E:0011b0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42
c:0082 p:0035 s:0552 E:001230 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23
c:0081 p:0095 s:0546 E:0012c0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103
c:0080 p:0054 s:0538 E:001338 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217
c:0079 p:0023 s:0533 E:0013a8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83
c:0078 p:0016 s:0528 E:001418 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52
c:0077 p:0022 s:0523 E:001488 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141
c:0076 p:0025 s:0518 E:001510 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:24
c:0075 p:0037 s:0510 E:001588 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36
c:0074 p:0013 s:0505 E:001660 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44
c:0073 p:0006 s:0502 E:001730 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12
c:0072 p:0029 s:0499 E:0017d8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308
c:0071 p:0011 s:0494 E:001700 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12
c:0070 p:0015 s:0489 E:001630 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44
c:0069 p:0006 s:0486 E:001900 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87
c:0068 p:0015 s:0482 E:001600 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43
c:0067 p:0038 s:0475 E:0019c0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:33
c:0066 p:0017 s:0469 E:001a70 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4 [FINISH]
c:0065 p:---- s:0466 e:000465 CFUNC  :tap
c:0064 p:0018 s:0462 E:001a40 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4
c:0063 p:0014 s:0456 E:001b30 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186
c:0062 p:0035 s:0450 E:001ba8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30
c:0061 p:0012 s:0445 E:001c10 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20
c:0060 p:0134 s:0442 E:0011c8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131
c:0059 p:0011 s:0432 E:0012f8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19
c:0058 p:0012 s:0427 E:001e80 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20
c:0057 p:0014 s:0421 E:001f40 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32
c:0056 p:0014 s:0416 E:002020 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166
c:0055 p:0028 s:0413 E:0020e0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21
c:0054 p:0033 s:0405 E:001ff0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166
c:0053 p:0112 s:0399 E:001f00 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30
c:0052 p:0154 s:0393 E:0021f0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252
c:0051 p:0075 s:0385 E:002278 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124
c:0050 p:0065 s:0378 E:0022f0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30
c:0049 p:0028 s:0372 E:002378 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189
c:0048 p:0050 s:0365 E:0023f8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253
c:0047 p:0015 s:0358 E:002480 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49
c:0046 p:0051 s:0350 E:002510 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31
c:0045 p:0155 s:0342 E:0025f8 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50 [FINISH]
c:0044 p:---- s:0330 e:000329 CFUNC  :each
c:0043 p:0014 s:0326 E:002588 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33
c:0042 p:0049 s:0321 E:0026b0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834
c:0041 p:0012 s:0315 E:000050 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:36 [FINISH]
c:0040 p:---- s:0312 e:000311 CFUNC  :catch
c:0039 p:0073 s:0307 E:000020 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:35
c:0038 p:0012 s:0301 E:000138 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/etag.rb:25
c:0037 p:0058 s:0290 E:0001c8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25
c:0036 p:0012 s:0281 E:000250 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12
c:0035 p:0038 s:0273 E:0002f8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232
c:0034 p:0010 s:0262 E:000368 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226
c:0033 p:0030 s:0257 E:000400 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613
c:0032 p:0014 s:0247 E:0004b0 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26
c:0031 p:0037 s:0244 E:000578 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97
c:0030 p:0016 s:0235 E:000488 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24
c:0029 p:0024 s:0228 E:000650 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12
c:0028 p:0030 s:0220 E:0006f8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59
c:0027 p:0012 s:0209 E:000770 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/web-console-3.5.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135
c:0026 p:0092 s:0203 E:000860 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/web-console-3.5.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28 [FINISH]
c:0025 p:---- s:0192 e:000191 CFUNC  :catch
c:0024 p:0011 s:0187 E:0007f8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/web-console-3.5.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18
c:0023 p:0030 s:0180 E:000928 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31
c:0022 p:0051 s:0173 E:000310 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36
c:0021 p:0012 s:0165 E:000a10 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24
c:0020 p:0007 s:0162 E:000af0 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69
c:0019 p:0019 s:0159 E:000ba0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26
c:0018 p:0016 s:0153 E:000ab8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69
c:0017 p:0049 s:0148 E:0009e0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24
c:0016 p:0049 s:0142 E:000c98 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13
c:0015 p:0061 s:0137 E:000d10 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79
c:0014 p:0047 s:0131 E:000d90 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25
c:0013 p:0105 s:0125 E:000e10 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22
c:0012 p:0026 s:0119 E:000eb0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22
c:0011 p:0039 s:0109 E:000f38 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.r
c:0010 p:0024 s:0102 E:000fc0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12
c:0009 p:0103 s:0094 E:001050 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125
c:0008 p:0012 s:0086 E:001100 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111
c:0007 p:0026 s:0074 E:001180 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:522
c:0006 p:0032 s:0068 E:0011f8 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225
c:0005 p:0275 s:0063 E:001308 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:605
c:0004 p:0040 s:0038 E:0013b0 METHOD /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:437
c:0003 p:0084 s:0026 E:001458 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:301 [FINISH]
c:0002 p:0160 s:0016 E:001510 BLOCK  /home/jafuentest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@uriji/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:---- s:0003 e:000002 (none) [FINISH]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a bug in MRI 2.4. Follow these threads [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-1202) and [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-4419)

Comment: Thanks! Updating to 2.4.1 solved the problem in my case.